# Add external JS to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a canvas to react component. Which I have achieved:

```
var React = require('react'),
    c = require('./../canvas_animation');

var Home = React.createClass({

 componentDidMount: function () {
    React.findDOMNode(this).childNodes[1].appendChild(c);
  },
```

This [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m3LLqtq8/) contains canvas animation.

Problem: Everything is working fine in react apart from mouse events? How can I make them work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(document).mousedown(function(e)
                {
                    onMouseDown();
                });

                $(document).mouseup(function(e)
                {
                    onMouseUp();
                }); 
            })
```

[Replicated](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12483/) here react having issue with events.

Comment: what mouse event do you want to use? What do you want to do?

Comment: Updated the question to include events. These are not working when rendered in react. I want this normal functionality but in react.

Comment: Why are you using `document` ? do you want those events to fire when they happen on the component?

Comment: yes component, but regardless this should work isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are binding those event to the document so it should work

Comment: Replicated issue of jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.js is using syntethic event system http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html. The first step would be to attach events on react node directly:

```
render: function() {
    return <div onMouseDown={onMouseDown} onMouseUp={onMouseUp}></div>;
}
```

then use mouse position from event args directly:

```
  function onMouseDown(e)
  {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    ...
  }
```

I also replaced Hello world with empty div because it impacts the size of stageHeight variable and managed to move balls on drag sometimes, you should find out what remaining parts should be updated. Here the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12491/

Comment: @GurpreetSingh event handlers are invoked, you can check in the debugger, but the code should be update further to rely on React event system fully